# Moving only specific files to new branch

Tags: git, github

I have branch1 with 10 files, while creating new branch as branch2, I want to select only four files into the new branch.

Is it possible in git, because while creating a new branch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might take a look at [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  Branch *names* are merely pointers, pointing to a specific commit.  Each commit contains a snapshot, of whatever is in the *index* at the time you make the snapshot.  (Each commit also "points back" to its parent commit(s) as well, and of course has an author, committer, and commit message.)

Making a new commit first writes out the index, then writes a commit referring to the saved index (a *tree* object) and also referring back to the *current*, or `HEAD`, commit.  Last, the new commit becomes the current / `HEAD` commit, by writing its ID into the branch name.  The branch name then points to the newest commit (the `HEAD` file contains only the branch name; it's the branch-name that points to the commit).

If you want a new commit to contain some specific set of files, you should add those files to the index and remove any other files from the index.  Whatever is in the index will become the snapshot contents of the *next* commit you make.

To see what is in the index right now, run `git ls-files`.  For a more verbose / detailed output, use `git ls-files --stage`, which shows which index slots (there can be more than one, during a conflicted merge; but otherwise everything is in slot zero) are occupied as well.

As in [Bertrand Martel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42404070/1256452), you can copy files into the index using `git checkout`:

```
git checkout <commit-specifier> -- <path> [ <path> ... ]
```

copies the file for each `<path>` from the specified commit—a branch name points to the *tip* commit on that branch, but you can use anything from [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) here—into the index, and then from the index into the work-tree.

You can also copy a file into the index by taking it from the work-tree:

```
git add <path> [ <path> ... ]
```

This copies whatever is in the work-tree at the given path into the index (specifically into slot zero, wiping out any other slots, which is why this resolves a merge conflict).

To remove a file from the index, use `git rm`, similarly to `git add`.  Note, though, that this removes it from *both* the index *and* the work-tree; to remove from the index only, use `git rm --cached`.

For complex scripting operations, you can use `git update-index` to make changes directly to the index, but this requires a lot more familiarity with the Git internals (you have to individually hash blob objects first, for instance, and know when to use `--add`, `--replace`, and so on).

Answer (score 24):

Create your new branch, remove all files in that branch, retrieve some files from another branch and commit changes :

```
# create a new branch
git checkout -b branch_name
# remove all files for this branch
git rm -rf .
# retrieve some files from master branch
git checkout master -- file1 file2 file3 file4
# commit changes
git commit -m "create new branch"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, This is work for small number of files, but what if I have around 100 files and want to move 40 files?

Comment: I've updated my post for another method, remove all files and grab only files  you want from other branches

Comment: Thanks may be I will try with this approach, makes sense.

Comment: Is it work for a folder ? I had tested and it don't find the folder