# Github action to copy specific folders from one branch to another in the same repo

Tags: github, github-actions

Is there a github action which allows me to copy specific folders (.eg. dist and static) from one branch to another in the same private repo. I appreciate any help.
here is what was trying to get it to work using Copycat action.

```
name: Copying static files

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - src # Set a branch name to trigger deployment


jobs:
  copy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Copycat
      uses: andstor/copycat-action@v3
      with:
        personal_token: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_TOKEN }}
        src_path: static.
        dst_path: /static/
        dst_owner: CompanyX
        dst_repo_name: MyRepo
        dst_branch: dest
        src_branch: src
        src_wiki: false
        dst_wiki: false
    - name: Copycat2
      uses: andstor/copycat-action@v3
      with:
        personal_token: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_TOKEN  }}
        src_path: dist.
        dst_path: /dist/
        dst_owner: CompanyX
        dst_repo_name: MyRepo
        dst_branch: des
        src_branch: src
        src_wiki: false
        dst_wiki: false
```

but I'm getting this error even though I have personal token setup in my profile.

> fatal: could not read Password for 'https://github.com': No such device or address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to commit to the same repository, you don't have to specify a personal token, just use `actions/checkout@v2` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131269/github-jobs-what-is-use-actions-checkout/67133122#67133122))

One solution to copy files between branch is to use `git checkout [branch] -- $files`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403917/moving-only-specific-files-to-new-branch)

The following workflow copy files from directory named `static` on source branch to branch named `dest`:

```yaml
name: Copy folder to other branch

on: [push]

jobs:
  copy:
    name: Copy my folder
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: copy
        env:
          SRC_FOLDER_PATH: 'static'
          TARGET_BRANCH: 'dest'
        run: |
          files=$(find $SRC_FOLDER_PATH -type f) # get the file list
          git config --global user.name 'GitHub Action'
          git config --global user.email 'action@github.com'
          git fetch                         # fetch branches
          git checkout $TARGET_BRANCH       # checkout to your branch
          git checkout ${GITHUB_REF##*/} -- $files # copy files from the source branch
          git add -A
          git diff-index --quiet HEAD ||  git commit -am "deploy files"  # commit to the repository (ignore if no modification)
          git push origin $TARGET_BRANCH # push to remote branch
```

Comment: I did not test the script, I just wanted to know can I use -S to sign the commit

Comment: The `git checkout ${GITHUB_REF##*/} -- $files` does not work, as it says ```fatal: invalid reference: source-branch
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.```. I even checkout-ed from `source-branch` earlier, so yes, the branch does exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check out a file from another branch, another option is to do the following:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3

- name: Fetch file from another branch
  run: |
    git fetch origin otherbranch:otherbranch --force
    git show otherbranch:filetoget.txt > filetoget.txt
    git diff
```

The `git diff` step is optional but quite useful if you want to see what's changed.